# Add minutes to date time column

Tags: 14.04, bash, sed, awk, perl

Thanks to various contributors resolving my previous request.

I need to add minutes to the date column to get new datetime stamp value. I have a file : `afile.txt`

```
1,2012-02-16,abc,aa,455,340
3,2015-02-16,dsa,dl,350,200
2,2015-02-16,aws,sw,555,180
4,2015-02-16,yyz,aa,1220,210
```

I have used awk (as provided to me by contributors earlier) --

```
awk -F, '/,/ {
    printf "%s, %s, %s, %s, %s %02d:%02d, %s\n",
           $1, $2, $3, $4,
           $2, int($5 / 100), $5 % 100,
           $6
}' afile.txt > bfile.txt

bfile.txt
1, 2012-02-16, abc, aa, 2012-02-16 04:55, 340
3, 2015-02-16, dsa, dl, 2015-02-16 03:50, 200
2, 2015-02-16, aws, sw, 2015-02-16 05:55, 180
4, 2015-02-16, yyz, aa, 2015-02-16 12:20, 210
```

I want to add column 5 and 6 and get the new timestamp.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming that the last field should be interpreted in the same fashion as the penultimate one i.e. `340` means an offset of 3 hours and 40 minutes.

If that is correct, then using GNU awk's [Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions) you could do

```
awk '
  BEGIN{FS=","; OFS=", "}
  {
    split($2,d,"-"); 
    t0 = mktime(d[1]" "d[2]" "d[3]" "int($5 / 100)" "$5 % 100" 0"); 
    $5 = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", t0); 
    $6 = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", t0 + 3600 * int($6 / 100) + 60 * ($6 % 100))
  } 1' afile.txt
1, 2012-02-16, abc, aa, 2012-02-16 04:55, 2012-02-16 08:35
3, 2015-02-16, dsa, dl, 2015-02-16 03:50, 2015-02-16 05:50
2, 2015-02-16, aws, sw, 2015-02-16 05:55, 2015-02-16 08:15
4, 2015-02-16, yyz, aa, 2015-02-16 12:20, 2015-02-16 14:30
```

If the last field is simply minutes, then the math for `$6` is easier:

```
awk '            
  BEGIN{FS=","; OFS=", "}
  {
    split($2,d,"-"); 
    t0 = mktime(sprintf("%d %d %d %d %d 0", d[1], d[2], d[3], int($5 / 100), $5 % 100)); 
    $5 = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", t0); 
    $6 = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", t0 + 60 * $6)  } 1' afile.txt
1, 2012-02-16, abc, aa, 2012-02-16 04:55, 2012-02-16 10:35
3, 2015-02-16, dsa, dl, 2015-02-16 03:50, 2015-02-16 07:10
2, 2015-02-16, aws, sw, 2015-02-16 05:55, 2015-02-16 08:55
4, 2015-02-16, yyz, aa, 2015-02-16 12:20, 2015-02-16 15:50
```

Comment: My fault. The last line is number of minutes that needs to be added to 5th column (date : yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm).

Comment: @ISingh please see updated answer

Comment: You are an angel. Thank you so much for helping me so quickly.